# Смайлики в EditText не отображаются

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть стандартный EditText :

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        style="@style/ToolbarText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center""
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Когда я пытаюсь ввести смайлик, они просто не отображается в строке EditText и ничего не происходит. Этот EditText является поиском, если то. что мне нужно найти состоит из смайликов, это проблема, ибо смайлики не вводятся вообще никак. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: Как текст? Предположу, что такого глифа просто нет в шрифте. Подключите свой шрифт.

Comment: Мне нужно осуществить поиск по смайликам

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Если обратится к [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat) то для начала нужно подключить поддержку смайликов в `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji:28.0.0"
}
```

так же можно использовать поле для ввода определенного образца:

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatEditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Так же стоит обратить внимание на шрифты, как вам уже было указано в комментариях. Вот есть несколько библиотек которые поддерживают ввод смайликов: [1](https://github.com/edsilfer/emoji-keyboard), [2](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon), [3](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard) может пригодится. Вот есть так же [статья](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/textdrawable-to-display-emojis-and-unicode-characters-in-android-35614168b8ad) по данному вопросу.